# Python3. Octree implementation engages a lot of memory. How to optimize?

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization, memory-management, octree

I develop game server and want to keep real-time objects positions on the maps. For this purpose I'm using octree algorithm. But for now my implementation engages a lot of RAM, for test I tried to populate several maps and even without objects octree engages about 1 GB + about 1 GB per map for objects (I store all objects in the dict and separately store list of guids for each octree nodes according to their coordinates).

Below my implementation:

```
class OctreeNode(object):

    MAX_CHILD_NODES = 8

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.x0 = kwargs.pop('x0')
        self.x1 = kwargs.pop('x1')
        self.y0 = kwargs.pop('y0')
        self.y1 = kwargs.pop('y1')
        self.z0 = kwargs.pop('z0')
        self.z1 = kwargs.pop('z1')

        self.root_node: OctreeNode = None
        self.parent_node: OctreeNode = None
        self.child_nodes = None

       self.objects = None
       self.guids = None

    def get_root_node(self) -> 'OctreeNode':
        return self.root_node

    def set_root_node(self, node: 'OctreeNode') -> None:
        self.root_node = node

    def get_parent_node(self) -> 'OctreeNode':
        return self.parent_node

    def set_parent_node(self, node: 'OctreeNode') -> None:
        self.parent_node = node

    def get_child_nodes(self) -> List['OctreeNode']:
        return self.child_nodes

    def set_child_nodes(self, nodes: List['OctreeNode']) -> None:
        self.child_nodes = nodes

    def can_contain_child_nodes(self) -> bool:
        update_dist = Config.World.Gameplay.update_dist

        return ((self.x1 - self.x0) > update_dist and
                (self.y1 - self.y0) > update_dist and
                (self.z1 - self.z0) > update_dist)

    def get_object(self, guid: int):
        return self.objects.get(guid, None)

    def set_object(self, obj: Union[Unit, Player]) -> None:
        if self.get_child_nodes():
            node = self._get_nearest_child_node(obj)
            node.set_object(obj)
        else:
            self.objects[obj.guid] = obj

    def should_contain_object(self, obj: Union[Unit, Player]) -> bool:
        return (self.x0 <= obj.x <= self.x1 and
                self.y0 <= obj.y <= self.y1 and
                self.z0 <= obj.z <= self.z1)

    def _get_nearest_child_node(self, obj: Union[Unit, Player]):
        for i in range(0, OctreeNode.MAX_CHILD_NODES):
            if self.child_nodes[i].should_contain_object(obj):
                return self.child_nodes[i]
```

And builder for this:

```
class OctreeBuilder(object):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):

        self.x0 = kwargs.pop('x0')
        self.x1 = kwargs.pop('x1')
        self.y0 = kwargs.pop('y0')
        self.y1 = kwargs.pop('y1')

        # FIXME: should get actual height for each map (use ADT, WDT, WMO for this purpose)
        self.z0 = -2000
        self.z1 = 2000

        self.root_node = OctreeNode(x0=self.x0, x1=self.x1, y0=self.y0, y1=self.y1, z0=self.z0, z1=self.z1)
        self.objects = kwargs.pop('objects', {})

    def build(self) -> OctreeNode:
        self._build_child_nodes(self.root_node, self.root_node)
        self.root_node.objects = self.objects
        return self.root_node

    def _set_objects(self) -> None:
        for obj in self.objects.values():
            self.root_node.set_object(obj)

    def _build_child_nodes(self, node: OctreeNode, root_node: OctreeNode) -> None:
        middle_x = (node.x0 + node.x1) / 2
        middle_y = (node.y0 + node.y1) / 2
        middle_z = (node.z0 + node.z1) / 2

        x = ((node.x0, middle_x), (middle_x, node.x1))
        y = ((node.y0, middle_y), (middle_y, node.y1))
        z = ((node.z0, middle_z), (middle_z, node.z1))

        child_nodes = []

        for i in range(1, OctreeNode.MAX_CHILD_NODES + 1):
            x0, x1 = x[i % 2 == 0]
            y0, y1 = y[(i & 3) % 3 == 0]
            z0, z1 = z[i > 4]

            child_node = OctreeBuilder._build_node(x0, x1, y0, y1, z0, z1)
            child_node.set_root_node(root_node)
            child_node.set_parent_node(node)

            if child_node.can_contain_child_nodes():
                self._build_child_nodes(child_node, root_node)
            else:
                child_node.guids = []

            child_nodes.append(child_node)

        node.set_child_nodes(child_nodes)

    @staticmethod
    def _build_node(x0: float, x1: float, y0: float, y1: float, z0: float, z1: float) -> OctreeNode:
        return OctreeNode(x0=x0, x1=x1, y0=y0, y1=y1, z0=z0, z1=z1)
```

I have spent a lot of time to find the ways to optimize memory usage. So, I tried to using tuple where possible (for example on the `middle_x` line of OctreeBuilder). Also I'm using `__slots__` (removed from the code above due to big code example). And so on. But it seems my optimizations are not enough. And for now my code can't be working because of a lot of engaged memory. Please, help me to optimize it!

P.S. to see the full code example you can visit my project on https://github.com/sergio-ivanuzzo/idewave-core (dev branch)

**NOTICE!**: I want (if possible) to keep object-oriented approach in my project. So, it will be very nice if answer for this question will contain class-based solution.

Also, according to @zch comment I tried to replace my `OctreeNode` class with `namedtuple`, but this approach only increased used memory.

**I want to keep in nodes next information:**

1. parent node
2. child nodes
3. coordinates (x0 x1 y0 y1 z0 z1)

if node is leaf node it also should keep list of objects ids.

**UPDATED**
For building octree for each map I load map coords from db. As test we can use next data:

```
x0 = -1277.08
x1 = 3814.58
y0 = 8437.5
y1 = 11831.2

builder = OctreeBuilder(x0=x0, x1=x1, y0=y0, y1=y1, objects=objects)
octree = builder.build()
# attach octree to map object to save it in memory
```

The object example:

```
{'max_rage': None, 'char_class': None, 'min_damage': None, 'stamina': None, 'resistance_arcane': 0, 'max_ranged_damage': None, 'unit_template_id': 11183, 'id': 2897, 'focus': None, 'gender': None, 'max_damage': None, 'intellect': None, 'armor': 20, 'x': 1940.93, 'region_id': 1, 'health': 300, 'max_focus': None, 'level': 1, 'min_offhand_damage': None, 'spirit': None, 'attack_power': None, 'y': -4322.39, 'max_health': 300, 'energy': None, 'unit_flags': None, 'max_offhand_damage': None, 'resistance_fire': 0, 'base_mana': 0, 'z': 27.7612, 'mana': 0, 'max_energy': None, 'display_id': 11686, 'unit_bytes_1': None, 'resistance_nature': 0, 'base_health': 300, 'orientation': None, 'scale_x': 1.0, 'max_mana': None, 'happiness': None, 'native_display_id': 11686, 'mod_cast_speed': None, 'resistance_frost': 0, 'unit_bytes_2': None, 'map_id': None, 'rage': None, 'max_happiness': None, 'faction_template': 35, 'strength': None, 'resistance_shadow': 0, 'ranged_attack_power': None, 'power_type': None, 'race': None, 'agility': None, 'min_ranged_damage': None,  '_tracked_guids': set(), '_target': None}
```

Comment: Don't use a class for nodes. Use tuple or maybe namedtuple.

Comment: @zch thanks for you comment. can you please clarify what do you mean? For now each node im my implementation stores coords (x, y, z) and if this is ending node, it also stores ids of objects. (it means that each node also stores additional list). Can you please add minimal implementation (if you want, in pseudo code) as answer?

Comment: What I mean is that you have no `class OctreeNode`. Instead, you would use a list in leaf node (list of objects) and 11 element tuple for other nodes (3 coordinates of the midpoint and 8 child nodes). It would be less readable, but it should take less memory. On the side, I am not sure if you are even using any benefits of the oct-tree. It looks like you could just build a grid.

Comment: @zch you want to say that my algorithm is incorrect so it's not octree ? If yes, can you please explain what have I missed to implement proper octree ?

Comment: @zch: `namedtuple` is just a function that creates a class. It doesn’t do anything that `class` can’t do already.

Comment: How do you use the above code? How many nodes do you create? Please edit your question according to: [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @CristiFati I have added small example of how I use this code to UPDATED part of my question. For each map I create about 300k nodes.

Comment: I's still not reproducible (*objects* is missing). Add **all* the code needed to reproduce the problem (as one that is willing to doesn't have to browse your repo which is pretty large), and the memory footprint, and probably a desired footprint. How many maps do you have simultaneously?

Comment: @CristiFati `objects` is dict of about 4k objects on map (expected count of objects is about 10k). How can I add them to make this example reproducible ? I have 65 maps simultaneously.

Comment: Add one object that could be  multiplied any number of times. Is it necessary that all the maps are "on" simultaneously? Same thing for objects on a map. You have roughly *65k* objects (I assume those are the root nodes only, and each will have how many descendent nodes?), which is normal to eat lots of memory. I think you'd need a design change (if possible).

Comment: Well, it's necessary when all the maps are in memory simultaneously only if players are on them. But, to build octree I need about 3 seconds. I think it's not good idea to remove map with octree from memory if no player are there. So I keep all maps in memory to avoid so long octree rebuilding. I have added object example (without fields that contains foreign keys).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200182/discussion-between-sergio-ivanuzzo-and-cristifati).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I have fixed the problem. First, I have decided to increase minimal size for nodes, thus `OctreeBuilder` returned less nodes. So, from 2 GB memory usage was reduced to 200 MB. Next, I have removed methods from `OctreeNode` class. So, I have left class without methods:

```
class OctreeNode(object):

    __slots__ = (
        'x0',
        'x1',
        'y0',
        'y1',
        'z0',
        'z1',
        'parent_node',
        'child_nodes',
        'guids'
    )

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.x0: float = kwargs.pop('x0')
        self.x1: float = kwargs.pop('x1')
        self.y0: float = kwargs.pop('y0')
        self.y1: float = kwargs.pop('y1')
        self.z0: float = kwargs.pop('z0')
        self.z1: float = kwargs.pop('z1')

        self.parent_node: Union[OctreeNode, None] = kwargs.pop('parent_node', None)
        self.child_nodes: Union[List, None] = None

        self.guids: Union[List, None] = None
```

Thanks to all for hints and for discussion. If you have another approaches for optimizing please let me know in the comments.

Comment: You can save even more space by storing all data in NumPy arrays (using child node indices instead of explicit references) - unsuitable for dynamic scenes though.